# How to convert the Entry input data to a float function? and write in on a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I'm a noob in writing python code.
Here is where I'm stuck right now.
The entry data input needs to be converted to the float for calculation the total. Also how can I get this data written on a new CSV file?
Sum_total = amount of milk *2.99 + amount of eggs * $2.49 + amount of orange juice * $3.25 + amount of corn flakes * $4.25.
Format of new csv file named receipt.csv : The first column should contain the name of each item; the second column should contain the number of each item that the customer would like to purchase; and the third column should contain subtotals for how much the customer is spending on each grocery item. After the rows for each item, your CSV should contain a “spacer” line filled with “--" in each cell. Finally, the bottom row of your CSV should be labeled “Total” and should contain the total amount that the customer needs to pay to Gerry’s
groceries

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import csv
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Gerry's groceries checkout")
root.configure( bg = "khaki1")

#Milk
milk_label = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Milk ($2.99):")
milk_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
milk_label.configure( bg = "khaki1")
milk_amount = tkinter.Entry(root, width=10)
milk_amount.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#Eggs
eggs_label = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Eggs ($2.49):")
eggs_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
eggs_label.configure (bg = "khaki1")
eggs_amount = tkinter.Entry(root, width = 10)
eggs_amount.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

#Orange Juice
oj_label = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Orange juice ($3.25):")
oj_label.grid( row = 0, column = 2)
oj_label.configure( bg = "khaki1")
oj_amount = tkinter.Entry(root, width = 10) 
oj_amount.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
#Corn Flakes
cf_label = tkinter.Label(root, text = "Corn flakes ($4.25)")
cf_label.grid( row = 1, column = 2)
cf_label.configure( bg = "khaki1")
cf_amount = tkinter.Entry(root, width = 10) 
cf_amount.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

def checkout():
    """Checkout the total price"""
    try:


        total_eggs = eggs_amount * 2.49
        total_oj = oj_amount *3.25
        total_cf = cf_amount *4.25
        total_milk = milk_amount *2.99
        total = total_eggs + total_oj + total_cf + total_milk
        return total

        #Create a CSV file
        with open("receipt.csv", "w") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator = "\n")
            row1 = ["Milks", "Orange Juice", "Eggs", "Corn flake"]
            row2 = [milk_amount,oj_amount,eggs_amount,cf_amount]
            row3 = [total]
            writer.writerow(row1)
            writer.writerow(row2)
            writer.writerow(row3)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Checkout complete!", "Eceipt was written to receipt.csv.")

    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Warning!", "Sorry, the receipt could not be written. Please check that only integer values were enterered.")

#Checkout
checkout_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = " Checkout", command = checkout)
checkout_button.configure( bg = "spring green")
checkout_button.grid(row = 0, column = 4)


#Quit
quit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = " Quit", command = root.destroy)
quit_button.configure( bg = "red2")
quit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 4)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

> The entry data input needs to be converted to the float for calculation the total.

Before that, you need to call `.get()` for the entry data; then, you can convert the gotten string to a number:

```
        total_eggs = int(eggs_amount.get()) * 2.49
        total_oj   = int(  oj_amount.get()) * 3.25
        total_cf   = int(  cf_amount.get()) * 4.25
        total_milk = int(milk_amount.get()) * 2.99
```

> Also how can I get this data written on a new CSV file?

First, you have to drop the `return total` line, so that the checkout function gets to the part where you already write to the file. Then, you just have to write what your assignment states:

```
            writer.writerow(["Milks",      milk_amount.get(), total_milk])
            writer.writerow(["Orange Juice", oj_amount.get(), total_oj  ])
            writer.writerow(["Eggs",       eggs_amount.get(), total_eggs])
            writer.writerow(["Corn flake",   cf_amount.get(), total_cf  ])
            writer.writerow(["------------",             "-", "-----"   ])
            writer.writerow(["Total",                     "", total     ])
```